# How to trigger user left site event using JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a website which performs financial search service for users that fill a form in my site. The search done by having a direct XML integration with the providers and such search may take up to one minute to complete. I would like to notify the server should the user decided to leave the site prior to the search completion.

I used `onunload` js event which works, however, it also triggered when the server complete the financial search and redirect the user to the "Service Found" page. Therefore, I get user left site notification for every user although user was redirect from server side to the "Service Found" page.

What would be the best way to detect if a user leaves a web page while not triggering the event when the server response and redirect to "Service Found" page?

I read Scott Mitchell article "Prompting a User to Save When Leaving a Page" ( https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml), however, it I wan unable to trigger the event only when user leaves the site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the form with AJAX instead ? You'll be able to deactivate your unload handler. Here's how it works with jQuery:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  $.post('/form-action', $(this).serialize(), function(responseText) {
    $(window).unbind('unload');

    // update the page with the response
    $('#response').html(responseText);

    // or redirect to the result page: window.location = 'new location';
});
```